# Unable to open Apple Configurator in my Mac

Tags: osx-yosemite, apple-configurator

I have installed the Configurator in to my mac. When I try to open the Configurator from Applications Folder , it is not opening. I am using Mac 10.10.1 with iTunes 12.0. Can any one suggest any solution ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you get any kind of errors, does the symbol appear in the dock?

I would start up activity manager and watch the processes when you try to launch the app, try and see what's happening.

I'm running Yosemite with Apple Configurator fine on my mac mini, if you cant work it out I would probably delete the application and reinstall making sure you are running the latest version of everything.

Comment: Thanks for your answer even it was late. I did the same by myself on the next day and it worked fine